# my laravel module project doesn't load in subdomain

Tags: laravel, module, subdomain, laravel-8, laravel-modules

I use nwdart module in my project and i upload my project on a sub domain but the part of my project that relate to modules doesn't load and give's me error
Target class [Modules\Sell\Http\Controllers\admin\sellController] does not exist.

Comment: check the case of the namespace, classname and filename ... case matters if it is on a case sensitive filesystem

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.